# what beat frequencies will be heard from the superposition of 3 sources of unequal frequency?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, biophysics, superposition

**1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data**
3 tuning forks of frequencies 200, 203, 207 Hz are sounded together. Find the beat frequency.

**2. Relevant equations**
Beat frequency= n1-n2 (n=frequency).

**3. The attempt at a solution**
I know that beat frequency is the difference in the frequencies of two superposing notes. But here 3 wave frequencies are given. The differences are 3, 4 and 7 Hz. 

**4. Conceptual doubt**
Which of these 3 beat frequencies will actually be heard by the ear? All 3, the lowest (3Hz), or some combination of the 3?

Comment: In general with three or more frequencies *all* combinations of beats are possible and furthermore beats from one combination of wave inputs can interfere with beats from another. In other words beats could interfere with beats. But with 3 or more waves interfering the observed superposition begins to appear quite chaotic at least in the time domain. Best to view as as a spectrum in the frequency domain.

Comment: Oh really? My book has n answer for this as 12. I've been wondering all the way like how did they get it? :/

Comment: Fundamentally beat frequencies come about from waves that interfere with one another. So the more fundamental wave frequencies you have, the more possibilities of interference.

Comment: So you say there might be more than one beat frequency?! If so can we find those more than one beat frequency by these normal calculative methods?

Comment: In principle yes. But in practice, in the reality of 3 dimensional space when you have more than two fundamental frequencies, more complex reflective boundaries and nonlinear media the considerations, calculations can become more complex. Definitely the beat of a different drummer.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help: http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/10f/Interference.pdf

Comment: @docscience  *Best to view as as a spectrum in the frequency domain*: beat frequencies do not appear in the spectrum. For example, the spectrum of $\cos 2 \pi f_1 t + \cos 2 \pi f_2 t$ contains the frequencies $\pm f_1$ and $\pm f_2$, but not $|f_1 - f_2|$ (except for some very particular cases such as $f_2=2f_1$...).

Comment: -1. The question you are asking needs to appear in sufficient detail on this page. It should not be necessary for users to follow links to other sites, which may be altered or disappear altogether. Also, it may not be clear which part of the link you are referring to.

Comment: @claudechuber so in the case of a piano tuner using a tuning fork to tune a specific key they listen and adjust tension until the frequency of the beat is minimized or else vanishes. So you are telling me that if I capture the same sound with a microphone and feed it to an FFT analyzer I won't see the beat? It will be there!

Comment: @sammy garbil edited the question

Comment: Ignore what the book says the answer is. What do you think the answer is?

Comment: @docscience : in reply to *I won't see the beat?*: you won't see it, that's exactly what I said. If you record a 440 Hz tuning fork together with a string at say 437 Hz, the FFT analyzer will show you peaks at 440 Hz and 437 Hz but not at 3 Hz. It you are familiar with Matlab, that's something you can check easily.  Note however the funny thing: if you introduce some non linear distortion in the process, then the 3 Hz will usually appear in the FFT.

Comment: @sammy gerbil I guessed the answer would be 7 as it's the difference between the lowest and highest frequency.is that right? Sam?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading and not useful. You will hear beats at 3, 4, 7Hz. But you will also hear beats between beats, ie at 4-3=1 Hz; the other differences (3, 4Hz) are already present. I don't know where 12Hz is coming from (3x4=12). ... I recommend that you do as Floris does in the duplicated qn : use software (eg spreadsheet) to model the sum of the 3 tuning forks and inspect the resulting waveform for yourself. (Floris' answer shows beats at 5Hz and also 1Hz.) That way you can have confidence in your answer and investigate the effect of phase- or amplitude- differences.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing the question to try to get it reopened.

Comment: @sammy gerbil still wondering how this would come under biophysics?

Comment: The mathematical answer does not tell us what the brain actually "hears" from this complex signal. The ears and brain form a filtering system which may automatically select what you listen to. In Claude Shuber's 1st diagram the 7Hz and 1Hz beats seems most easily recognisable by eye - but which of these does the ear actually pick up on? You only hear beats below 15Hz, which suggests that the brain is trying to count. Counting at 1Hz is much easier than at 7Hz, so perhaps the brain "hears" a 7Hz background with a 1Hz beat superposed on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question does not specify what is the *beat frequency* in the case of more than 2 frequencies, so I will sketch what one could expect it to be. Each pair of frequencies produces the following beats: 3 Hz for the (200, 203) pair, 4 Hz for the (203, 207) pair and 7 Hz for the (200, 207) pair. The resulting sound combines those three beats. What could be called the *beat frequency*? The most natural choice is to pick the frequency which would be the fundamental frequency of those three beats, that is, the greatest common divisor of 3, 4, 7, which is 1. And indeed, the sum of the three beats is a more complex beat, periodic with period 1 Hz, hence the definition makes sense.

So the answer to your question is: the beat frequency is 1 Hz. Here is how it looks, the 1 Hz periodic pattern is visible:
[image]
Note that the *beat frequency* as defined above does not necessarily exist: if for example you have three frequences $f$, $f+3$, and $f+2\pi$,  then the differences $3$, $2\pi$ and $2\pi-3$ have no greatest common divisor (there are no integers $p$, $q$, $r$ and no positive real number $d$ such that $3 = pd$, $2\pi = qd$ and $2\pi-3 = rd$). In the latter case, the resulting sound is not periodic.

Here is how it looks when there is no GCD, and hence no periodic pattern:
[image]

Comment: @John Rennie & al.: it is a bit frustrating to spend time answering a question, and find that the question has been put on hold later. But I
believe that is the rule of the game.

Comment: still I am flabbergasted on why this question went off topic :/

Comment: @user129402 : It is a good (useful) question. But the site has a very strict policy on "homework-like" questions such as this, regardless of their usefulness. You have shown effort and I think you are asking a conceptual question about what beats can be heard in such cases, rather than simply "show me how to do the calculation". In any case, your question may be a duplicate of [Beat frequency for 3 waves](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173372) which Floris answers by simply showing the waveform which results from the sum of 3 frequencies.

Comment: @sammy gerbil. Thanks for the link but sorry I couldn't understand the programming or whatsoever stuff that the answer had :/ I M still confused on how to find beat frequency for the waves and that question appears too often in my assignment :/ some suggests using Fourier series. And found another question like that which goes on like this n+1, n, n-1 are the frequencies ,what will be their beat frequency? I thought it would be 1 since it's the GCD for those 3 factors but the answer contrary to mine says 2 which means they subtracted the lowest and highest frequencies?! I M yet to clarify this

Comment: For frequencies n-1, n, n+1 there will be beats at differences of 1, 1 & 2 Hz and also 2-1=1, 1+1=2 and 1+2=3Hz. The 1Hz beat will dominate because there are more of them. Not all answers given on the internet are correct. I urge you to set up a spreadsheet (eg Excel) to model the sum of 3 sinusoids to convince yourself what happens.

Comment: @user129402 : I added for you two figures illustrating the two cases whether the GCD exists or not.

Comment: Wah! Thanks Claude! Finally enlightened :') that illustrations did help. :)