# Is 3 Dissonant sounds considered as Beat Frequency or would it be a different type dissonance?

Tags: waves, acoustics, superposition

Earlier Today, I had a conversation for physics and the teacher gave a question stating: Keys "A" and middle "C" were pressed which created a Frequency of 440 Hz, A tuning fork was also hit, what does it create. As a Musician, I understand that A and C does not make any sounds, and the fork is kind of useless. Would I be in the right to assume that it does not make beat frequency?

Comment: welcome to stackexchange. What do you mean, "As a Musician, I understand that A and C does not make any sounds," of course it does?! and in which sense would the fork be useless?

Comment: As in tuning the notes, having a C and A pressed with a tuning fork would be quite senseless because C and A isn't a good tuning tone on the keyboard, Also Thanks! This community seems very nice Hopefully I get better at physics xD

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Typically a tuning fork will give you 440Hz. Also, the A will give you 440Hz. It makes perfect sense to hit both the fork and the A, and listen for beats. If you don't get any you know you're in tune. What's the question?

Comment: I, apologize for writing so in consistently, my Question would be "Does 3 waves of sound coming from 3 sources still create beat frequency?"

Comment: Yes, it does, and no, it's still called a beat. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173372/beat-frequency-for-3-waves#296627

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beat frequency for 3 waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173372/beat-frequency-for-3-waves)